# generate graph using macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using this macro to generate graph which I take value from another sheets.
How can I simplified this by stopping to add series when not detected sheet1 dont have any input in column A.

```
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("CH 1").Activate
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries.MarkerStyle = False
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "='Sheet1'!$A$2"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='data'!$B$2:$B$400"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "='Sheet1'!$A$3"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='data (2)'!$B$2:$B$400"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Name = "='Sheet1'!$A$4"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).Values = "='data (3)'!$B$2:$B$400"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Name = "='Sheet1'!$A$5"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).Values = "='data (4)'!$B$2:$B$400"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Name = "='Sheet1'!$A$6"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(5).Values = "='data (5)'!$B$2:$B$400"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).Name = "='Sheet1'!$A$7"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(6).Values = "='data (6)'!$B$2:$B$400"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(7).Name = "='Sheet1'!$A$8"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(7).Values = "='data (7)'!$B$2:$B$400"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(8).Name = "='Sheet1'!$A$9"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(8).Values = "='data (8)'!$B$2:$B$400"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(9).Name = "='Sheet1'!$A$10"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(9).Values = "='data (9)'!$B$2:$B$400"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(10).Name = "='Sheet1'!$A$11"
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(10).Values = "='data (10)'!$B$2:$B$400"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Your question was a bit incoherent, so please comment if I misinterpreted what you are after.

```
Dim wks as Worksheet
Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1")

If WorksheetFunction.Count(wks.Columns(1)) <> 0 Then

    'insert your code here

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you notice that I repeat this(see below) line to add more value/series into my graph.
How can I intergrate with your code there.

```
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "='Sheet1'!$A$2"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='data'!$B$2:$B$400"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "='Sheet1'!$A$3"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = "='data (2)'!$B$2:$B$400"
```